# Automatically change a file's name when I assign it as an object

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like my procedure (which is a simple copy paste from one file to another) to be able to take into account the change of the file's name.

It's weekly procedure so that the week number is updated every week in the file's name (Variation_week44 then Variation_week45 and so on...)
Here is my (unsuccessful) attempt to do so (obviously error shows up at the line "Set wsDest: [...]" :

```
Sub test()
    Dim L060 As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim SelectionL060 As Long
    Dim Adestination As Long
    Dim WeekFolder As String

    'This cell would contain the week number
    WeekFolder = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
                            

    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set L060 = Workbooks("L060.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Variation_week & Weekfolder &.xlsm").Worksheets("RM consumption")
    '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
    SelectionL060 = L060.Cells(L060.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A and Offset property moves down 1 row
    Adestination = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    '3. Copy & Paste Data
    L060.Range("A2:M" & SelectionL060).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Adestination)
    '4. Close workbook
    Workbooks("L060.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA see's `Workbooks("TEXT")`, you wanted `Workbooks("Text" & Variable & "Text")`. 
 You just forgot the quotes...``"Variation_week" & Weekfolder & ".xlsm"``

Comment: Also note that if you use something `Set L060 = Workbooks("L060.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")` the workbook needs to be open before the code runs. Otherwise you need to use something like `Set L060 = Workbooks.Open(yourPathAndFile)` see [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open). Also you don't need the workbooks name if it is the same the VBA code is written in, you can use `ThisWorkbook` instead.